# Delete an element from a generic list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, ienumerable

I can´t remove an element from an IEnumerable list, but this list is a reference to a List ,  a private attribute of an other class.
If I put `personsCollection.Remove(theElement)` in the same class (class Manager), it works perfect, but I need to delete the element since the other class (class ManagerDelete). Please how can I do this?
Thanks.

```
class Other
{
  //Some code
  public IEnumerable<Person> SearchByPhone (string value)
    {
        return from person in personCollection
               where person.SPhone == value
               select person;
    }
 }

class ManagerDelete
{ 
//Some code
IEnumerable<Person> auxList= SearchByPhone (value);
//I have a method for delete here  
}

class Manager
{ 
//Some code
 private List<Person> personsCollection = new List<Person>();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't delete from an `IEnumerable<T>` you need to make it of type `IList<T>` to add/remove items directly from it.

Comment: `IList` is not necessary, `ICollection` would be enough.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand what an `IEnumerable` Interface allows you to do.

I'v listed below the list of Interfaces that you should use by design, as and when required in differnt circumstances. In your example `IList` is what you will need to use.

- ICollection  Defines general characteristics (e.g., size, enumeration,
  and thread safety) for all non-generic collection types.
- ICloneable   Allows the implementing object to return a copy of itself 
  to the caller.
- IDictionary  Allows a non-generic collection object to represent its
  contents using key/value pairs.
- IEnumerable  Returns an object implementing the IEnumerator interface 
  (see next table entry).
- IEnumerator  Enables foreach style iteration of collection items.
- IList    Provides behavior to add, remove, and index items in a
  sequential list of objects.

Comment: Don't forget there is a difference between `IList` and `IList<T>`, `List` may implement `IList` but other strongly typed lists may not.

Answer (score 3):

Darren is right.
Without converting to a list you can do:

```
personCollection = personCollection.Except(SearchByPhone(value));
```

in ManagerDelete.

Comment: +1 for using Except, however be wary that by replacing `personCollection` any other objects that have have a reference to `personCollection` will still point at the old one, this can be worked around by using a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) or similar class to act as an indirection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ToList` to convert the `IEnumerable` to a `List` and then you can remove stuff from it.

```
var auxList= SearchByPhone (value).ToList();
auxList.Remove(something);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the `IEnumerable` to an `IList`. This will work if the `IEnumerable` is really a `List`. However this is a bad design. If you want to remove items, you should expose the list as an `IList`, not `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

An `IEnumerable` is literally just an interface to say, I've got this collection, you can iterate over it.

If you take a look at the actual details of the IEnumerable interface, it doesn't contain much, only a method to allow callers to iterate over it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/9eekhta0.aspx

The reason why `List` types can allow you to remove them, is it's built *on top* of the IEnumerable interface, giving you more functionality. It is supposed to represent a collection of objects you can manipulate. Whereas an `IEnumerable` is simply not designed to do this.

The `Remove` method actually stems from the underlying `ICollection` interface that `List` also implements:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bye7h94w.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers: your data structure choice doesn't seem to be adequate. If you really plan to remove elements from a container, your container *must not be* an `IEnumerable<>` in the first place!

Consider the following choices:

- switch from `IEnumerable<>` to `ICollection<>`;
- replace removing with filtering out (`.Where()`) and obtaining a separate filtered `IEnumerable<>`.